# Why won't my WPF bound Visibility property update?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a textblock in my XAML where the Visibility is bound to a property in my viewmodel. When the window first loads, the value from the viewmodel determines the visibility correctly (I tried manually overriding the backing store variable value and it works great, hiding the control as I need). However, when I change the property value the visibility doesn't change.

Here's the XAML for the control:

```
<TextBlock Text="Click the button" Style="{StaticResource Message}" Visibility="{Binding NoResultsMessageVisibility}" />
```

The "NoResultsMessageVisibility" property that I bind to is this:

```
    public Visibility NoResultsMessageVisibility
    {
        get { return _noResultsMessageVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _noResultsMessageVisibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NoResultsMessageVisibility");
        }
    }
```

NotifyPropertyChange raises a PropertyChanged event for the provided name using standard INotifyPropertyChanged.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

### EDIT

In response to the comments / answer so far.

The program is super simple so there's no parallelism / multithreading used.
The DataContext is set only once when the window loads, using:

```
new MainWindow { DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() }.ShowDialog();
```

The binding does seem to work when first loaded. I've noticed as well that a textbox I have bound to a property isn't updating when I change the property. However, the property is definitely updating when I change the textbox as the value is used as the basis for a command that's bound to a button. As the text changes, the button is enabled and disabled correctly and when I click it the value from the property is correct. Again, if I set a value against the backing store variable, this shows in the textbox when the window first loads.

Comment: Normally you'd check if the new value is identical before setting it and raising the notification (because only if it's not identical the value actually *changed* as the event suggests), but that should not prevent binding updates of course.

Comment: Are you updating the property via the primary thread?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness: That should not matter at all.

Comment: Are you sure the binding works in the first place? Check the output window for binding errors

Comment: I've run it through. I can't see any binding errors. Just stuff about assemblies loading and the like.

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it or delete the question, please; answered questions should not hang about looking unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. I'm a dozy dork :)

I have copied some code from another class and for some reason I'd added the `PropertyChanged` event to my viewmodel's interface, rather than implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the interface. D'Oh!

Answer (score 1):

Don't see anything wrong with this, is it possible that the DataContext gets changed, so the binding breaks? (You only specify the path, so it's relative to the current DataContext)

Comment: The context is set only when the window opens, using...new MainWindow { DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() }.ShowDialog();

Comment: And the value you set by default is loaded to the control once? So if you start it with the backing field at Collapsed the control is collapsed.

Comment: Yes. (Ignore this bit, need to hit minimum length)

Comment: Can't think of anything else right now, sorry. Might want to check the output window after the property changed, maybe it shows errors.